# Getting values from enum in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

I'm using enum for select options in thymeleaf and I can't see them or insert them in the database. There is nothing in the dropdown list.
[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="roomType">Rooms</label>
     <select class="form-select selectpicker show-tick" th:field="*{property.roomType}" id="rooms">
          <option value="">Nothing selected</option>
          <option th:each="property.roomType : ${T(com.realestate.petfriendly.entity.RoomType).values()}"
                  th:value="${property.roomType}"
                  th:text="${property.roomType}">
          </option>
     </select>
 </div>
```

class

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "RoomType")
private RoomType roomType;
```

and enum

```
public enum RoomType {
        
    GARSONJERA("garsonjera"), JEDNOIPOSOBAN("jednoiposoban"), DVOSOBAN("dvosoban"),
    DVOIPOSOBAN("dvoiposoban"), TROSOBAN("trosoban"), TROIPOSOBAN("troiposoban"),
    CERVOROSOBAN("cetvorosoban"), CETVOROIPOSOBAN("cetvoroiposoban"), VISESOBAN("visesoban");

    private String roomType;

    private RoomType(String roomType) {
        this.roomType = roomType;
    }

    public String getRoomType() {
        return this.roomType;
    }
```

}

I'm not sure why it doesn't show me anything

Comment: Can you check in the controller that the value is loaded into your map correctly in the `property`? Every value I use in Thymeleaf is loaded into a Map in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is available for me.

class

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Demo {

    private RoomType roomType;
}
```

enum

```
public enum RoomType {

    GARSONJERA("garsonjera"), JEDNOIPOSOBAN("jednoiposoban"), DVOSOBAN("dvosoban"),
    DVOIPOSOBAN("dvoiposoban"), TROSOBAN("trosoban"), TROIPOSOBAN("troiposoban"),
    CERVOROSOBAN("cetvorosoban"), CETVOROIPOSOBAN("cetvoroiposoban"), VISESOBAN("visesoban");

    private final String roomType;

    private RoomType(String roomType) {
        this.roomType = roomType;
    }

    public String getRoomType() {
        return this.roomType;
    }
}
```

controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("demo")
    public String demo(Model model){
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.setRoomType(RoomType.CERVOROSOBAN);
        model.addAttribute(demo);
        return "test/demo";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="rooms">Rooms</label>
    <select class="form-select selectpicker show-tick" th:field="*{demo.roomType}" id="rooms">
        <option value="">Nothing selected</option>
        <option th:each="value : ${T(com.bluray.boot.business.test.RoomType).values()}"
                th:value="${value}"
                th:text="${value}">
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I use spring-boot 2.3.6.release

Comment: Thank you. I replaced property.roomType with value in each, text, and value and it worked. Can you please give me a few more details why this way worked?

Comment: Maybe you have some misunderstandings about `th:each`. Just like `for(Item item:items)`, you only need to fill in `item`, like `th:each="item : items"`.`items` are `enums.values()`, you just use `item` that is an enum.